# Database deploy with updates

Tags: php, mysql, database, deployment, sql-update

Does anybody know how to do smart database update in realtime.

E.g. I have a site with a great database. Suddenly I've made some code changes and database structure and data changes. Is there any standard plan to do it with deploy script or any deploy soft? In realtime without stopping the site?

E.g. switch between two clone databases or smth like that. How do experienced people do that?

Site is written in php, database is MySql.

Thanx!

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [DBdeploy](http://dbdeploy.com/)? There's a [good article here](http://davedevelopment.co.uk/2008/04/14/how-to-simple-database-migrations-with-phing-and-dbdeploy.html) on managing database deployments using [Phing](http://phing.info/trac/) and DBdeploy

Comment: What he said. We've used DBDeploy before in both .NET and Java. Works like a charm.

Comment: Yes, this is good tool and article. And it suit to my task. But what if we have to do big batch update and need to save site working? 

# <exec  
#             command="${progs.mysql} -h${db.host} -u${db.user} -p${db.pass} ${db.name} &lt; ${build.dbdeploy.deployfile}"  
#             dir="${build.dir}"  
#             checkreturn="true" />  

do sql query, but this query with drop tables or updates can make the database server response slowly or make some tables unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Red Gate MySQL Compare has a 14-day fully functional trial. It preserves data when doing schema changes. There is also a separate MySQL Data Compare tool.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/mysql-compare/