# deploying code changes

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-deployment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best Practices for Code/Web Application Deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005298/best-practices-for-code-web-application-deployment)

I don't know if this is relevant to stackoverflow or not.

I always update & test code locally, then when it's time to upload the changes it's giving me a nightmare.

Like I will either have to go through Git repo & check what I've done & selectively upload files (not to mention DB changes) or I'll have to upload the whole thing all over again.

Selectively uploading files & applying DB changes is a headache & the full upload results in interruption of service for a few minutes or even worse.

**Is there some standard way of doing this?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289201/database-deploy-with-updates

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754676/how-to-auto-deploy-web-app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+deploy

Answer (score 0):

codeigniter specific -

- name your codeigniter application folder something relevant - the date or your version number. do the same with the system folder so you can quickly see what version of codeigniter you are running.
- if you need to do a full upload heres how to do it with no interruption - name the application folder with a newer date or version. upload the folder. then in your index.php file change the name of the application folder to new version. besides switching to new version with no down time - it also gives you instant roll back if you find a bug - just change the application name back in your index file. much less stress then trying to selectively replace files on a live site.
- you need to get an app like SmartGit or similar so you can do your git tracking and changes locally on your computer. make your commits locally - you will do it more often because its local so you will have a better commit history - and will be much faster when you need to push to remote.
- small point but if you put your application and system folders one level above the index.php file -- its much much more secure, and it keeps things organized if you have different application folders.